# Finding principal curvatures and principal curvature directions

Tags: differential-geometry

Let I = $du^2$ + $2cos(t)dudv$ + $dv^2$ and II = $2sin(t)dudv$, where $t(u,v)$ is a smooth function in $(u,v)$

Compute the principal curvature and principal curvature directions

I have seen it done in the following format

\begin{bmatrix}
l & m \\
m & n 
\end{bmatrix}

Subtract

\begin{bmatrix}
kE & kF \\
kF & kG 
\end{bmatrix}

and to find the determinant of that and set it equal to 0.

We are given I and II so we can find E, F, and G along with l, m, and n.

$E = 1$, $F=cos(t)$, $G = 1$, $l = 0$, $m = sin(t)$, $n = 0$

So, after the subtraction I get

\begin{bmatrix}
-k & sin(t)-kcos(t \\
sin(t)-kcos(t) & -k 
\end{bmatrix}

and we set the determinant of this equal to 0 and solve for k, k will give the principle curvature(s). For the determinant I have gotten

$k^2 - (sin^2(t) - ksin(t)cos(t) - ksin(t)cos(t) + k^2cos^2(t) = 0$

$k^2 (1-cos^2(t)) + 2kcos(t)sin(t) - sin^2(t) = 0$

At this point do I just use the quadratic formula to find the values of k? With

$a = 1-cos^2(t)$, $b = 2sin(t)cos(t)$, $c = -sin^2(t)$

I just want to make sure that I am on the right track before I contine, I ended up getting

$(-2sin(t)cos(t) +/- sqrt(-4sin^2(t)))/(2-2cos^2(t)$

which means I am ending towards imaginary numbers.

Comment: Simplify? You can divide through by $\sin t$. I haven't looked further.

Comment: Yeah I think there was a calculational error in there. Shouldn't have gotten a negative under the square root. K ends up being -1.

Comment: Now I am trying to find out how to write the christoffel symbols for a first fundamental form that looks like I = f(u,v)(du^2+dv^2). I can find E and G (F=0). Just not sure how to find the partials of f(u,v) with respect to u and v.

Comment: This is now a different question. Your answers will involve $f_u$ and $f_v$, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I was just over thinking it. The teacher said we can use $f_u$ and $f_v$ for that.